# Validation error when posting json data with node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, validation, post, axios

///api call from react with axios i have created axios instance

```
export const register = (correctInput) => {
  console.log(correctInput);
  axios
    .post("/api/auth/register", correctInput)
    .then((res) => console.log(res.data))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

///correctInput  here i am getting everything which is required to post the data

```
Object { username: "test", mobileNo: "0000000000", email: "test@gmail.com", password: "test" }
apicall.js:5
```

​///userschema

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    name: { type: String },
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    mobileNo: { type: Number, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    address: [
      {
        locality: { type: Number, unique: true },
        pincode: { type: Number, unique: true },
        city: { type: String, unique: true },
        state: { type: String, unique: true },
        country: {
          type: String,
          unique: true,
        },
        desc: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
      },
    ],
    isAdmin: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

///register code form my backend

```
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const newUser = new User({
    username: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email,
    mobileNo: req.body.mobileNo,
    password: CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
      req.body.password,
      process.env.SEC_PASS
    ).toString(),
  });

  try {
    const savedUser = await newUser.save();
    res.status(201).json(savedUser);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

///This is the error i am giving everything which is requires but its sending me velidation error

```
Error: User validation failed: username: Path `username` is required., email: Path `email` is required., mobileNo: Path `mobileNo` is required.
    at ValidationError.inspect (F:\PICKO\PICOMERN\picko-backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validation.js:48:26)
```

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of things, your code is correct. This may be a problem with the parsing of JSON data.

In your main file(backend) you must do `app.use(express.json());` or optionally you can use `app.use(express.json());`

Comment: i have used in my index js file